# Chrome DevTools React Profiler timings vs. reality

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, rendering, profiling, react-devtools

In the React Profiler in Chrome DevTools the timings for the app re-rendering are as follows:

[image]

That means 210ms to re-render the whole app. In reality it takes around 2 seconds which is a lot more then profiler shows. The same situation regarding the 2 seconds loading is when DevTools are not open, so it can't be some overhead processing. Also in the app's production build it takes roughly the same time to re-render.

I have to mention that this is development version of the app, the `Highlight updates when components render` is OFF, `Always parse hook names from source` is OFF. No fetch requests were realized in this render.

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Use the built-in performance profiler in devtools to get the overview of what happens overall.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I see. But unfortunately from that one I am not able decode what is wrong. I am not sure if I can share the profile here, but here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sm9AiRnkzowlIVHXgXNFDStobYh4vQPk

Comment: Look at the `Bottom-Up` and you'll see parseISO takes most of the time. Make sure to not have any selection in the flamegraph, i.e. click on an empty space, and zoom the flamegraph to fit in the view horizontally because only the visible part is analyzed.